# Audio trouble, the devices disappeared

Tags: sound

While trying to add the possibility to have sound simultaneously on hdmi and speakers, I tried that by installing Pulse and paprefs. It did not worked and also it broke my sound. So I uninstalled pulseaudio to return as it was but it did not. Now I don't even have Sound. So I installed it. Now the problem is that there is no device in Sound list.

Comment: I made progress by reinstalling paprefs then
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
reboot
then when my session opened, I had to do 
pulseaudio -D to had it work correctly

how do I make the change permanent?

Comment: oh and hdmi sound is not working now, only speakers and simultaneous are working since latests changes.

Comment: can anyone help me figure out what this is?
# df
...
/dev/loop1                   83456      83456          0 100% /snap/core/2844
/dev/loop0                    2944       2944          0 100% /snap/pulseaudio/9
/dev/loop2                   83456      83456          0 100% /snap/core/2898
...